# Webform Option Limit: How to write a module to change the number to subtract from the limit?

Tags: webforms

I've used the option limit handler before without problems, but now I have a new scenario.
I have a limit of 200 seats and each user can reserve up to a maximum of 5 seats. The user chooses the number of seats from the element seats_number(of type number).

Example: 200 seat limit, user selects 4 seats, new limit is 200-4=196.

What should I change in the settings handlers?

Thank you so much for help me.

Comment: The maintainer said “This will require a similar solution to the options limits handler but built via custom code or dedicated contribs module.” https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3382806 Are you asking for help with authoring that module?

Comment: Yes @cilefen, I'm the same person.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request to write code from scratch, which is against the site rules.